# Develop a statistical test to distinguish two products

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, repeated-measures, ordinal-data

I have a data set from a customer survey, I want to deploy a statistical test to see whether there is significance difference between product 1 and product 2.

Here is a data set of customers' reviews.

The rate is from very bad,bad,okay,good,to very good.

```
customer    product1    product2
1           very good   very bad
2           good        bad
3           okay        bad
4           very good   okay
5           bad         very good
6           okay        good
7           bad         okay
8           very good   very bad
9           good        good
10          good        very good
11          okay        okay
12          very good   good
13          good        good
14          very good   okay
15          very good   okay
```

What methods should I use to see if there is any difference betw these two products?

Comment: Please note that @Glen_b's answer gives superior advice, compared to the answer you accepted. Perhaps I should say that you can change an accepted answer at any time (not everybody is aware of that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ranking by different judges, one can use the Friedman test.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test

You may convert ratings from very bad to very good to numerics of -2, -1, 0, 1 and 2. Then put data in long form and apply friedman.test with customer as the blocking factor:

```
> mm
   customer variable value
1         1 product1     2
2         2 product1     1
3         3 product1     0
4         4 product1     2
5         5 product1    -1
6         6 product1     0
7         7 product1    -1
8         8 product1     2
9         9 product1     1
10       10 product1     1
11       11 product1     0
12       12 product1     2
13       13 product1     1
14       14 product1     2
15       15 product1     2
16        1 product2    -2
17        2 product2    -1
18        3 product2    -1
19        4 product2     0
20        5 product2     2
21        6 product2     1
22        7 product2     0
23        8 product2    -2
24        9 product2     1
25       10 product2     2
26       11 product2     0
27       12 product2     1
28       13 product2     1
29       14 product2     0
30       15 product2     0
> 
> friedman.test(value~variable|customer, data=mm)

        Friedman rank sum test

data:  value and variable and customer
Friedman chi-squared = 1.3333, df = 1, p-value = 0.2482
```

The ranking of the difference between 2 products is not significant.

Edit:

Following is the output of regression:

```
> summary(lm(value~variable+factor(customer), data=mm))

Call:
lm(formula = value ~ variable + factor(customer), data = mm)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
  -1.9   -0.6    0.0    0.6    1.9 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         4.000e-01  9.990e-01   0.400    0.695
variableproduct2   -8.000e-01  4.995e-01  -1.602    0.132
factor(customer)2   6.248e-16  1.368e+00   0.000    1.000
factor(customer)3  -5.000e-01  1.368e+00  -0.365    0.720
factor(customer)4   1.000e+00  1.368e+00   0.731    0.477
factor(customer)5   5.000e-01  1.368e+00   0.365    0.720
factor(customer)6   5.000e-01  1.368e+00   0.365    0.720
factor(customer)7  -5.000e-01  1.368e+00  -0.365    0.720
factor(customer)8   9.645e-16  1.368e+00   0.000    1.000
factor(customer)9   1.000e+00  1.368e+00   0.731    0.477
factor(customer)10  1.500e+00  1.368e+00   1.096    0.291
factor(customer)11  7.581e-16  1.368e+00   0.000    1.000
factor(customer)12  1.500e+00  1.368e+00   1.096    0.291
factor(customer)13  1.000e+00  1.368e+00   0.731    0.477
factor(customer)14  1.000e+00  1.368e+00   0.731    0.477
factor(customer)15  1.000e+00  1.368e+00   0.731    0.477

Residual standard error: 1.368 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3972,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2486 
F-statistic: 0.6151 on 15 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.8194
```

[image]

Comment: Using Friedman's test is an overkill. It's like recommending to use ANOVA when there are two groups only; then it simply reduces to a t-test.

Comment: This regression analysis is incorrect. You have treated customer as a *continuous* variable instead of a factor. If you fix this, by changing it to a factor, you get a *p*-value of 0.1316, i.e., the same as from a paired *t*-test.

Comment: I had realized that it should be a factor, but I did not change it since my emphasis was on Friedman test. But since the sample size is small, I think a non-parametric test (rather than t-test) would be more appropriate here. I have corrected the regression part in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

1. One possibility is you could use the sign test.

   This relies on the comparisons within customers to see whether their rating from product1 to product2 went up, down, or stayed the same (under the binomial sign test the assumption is that you only get "up" or "down" results, but there are several common ways to approach the within-pair ties, such as customer 9's `good` vs `good`).

   One common approach is to exclude the tied ratings like customer 9's (so that the conclusion is about the relative proportion of up-vs-down differences in the population, assuming random sampling of customers).

   In this case you had 4 customers who gave higher ratings to the second product, 8 who gave lower, and three who gave the same.

   In that case, with your data, 4 of one sign and 8 of the other, a two-tailed sign test would not come close to rejection at any typical significance level. Here's the analysis in R:

   ```
   > binom.test(4,12)

           Exact binomial test

   data:  4 and 12
   number of successes = 4, number of trials = 12, p-value = 0.3877
   alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
   95 percent confidence interval:
    0.09924609 0.65112449
   sample estimates:
   probability of success 
                0.3333333
   ```

   The p-value is quite high.
2. Now *if* you're prepared to assign scores (or even just to rank) to the relative sizes of the changes in ratings within each pair -- that is to say, whether customer 2's "good" to "bad" change is bigger, smaller or the same as customer 4's "very good" to "okay", and so on, then you could apply a signed rank test on those ranks or by doing a paired permutation test on assigned scores (though you must also deal with heavy ties, this can readily be done by permuting the sets of ranks or scores you actually have).

There are some other choices you might consider -- but I don't think choice of analysis will change the outcome; I think they'll all fail to reject at typical significance levels on this data.

Comment: Sign test is an inferior predecessor of the Signed-ranks test, both developed by Wilcoxon. Therefore I would not recommend it. As for assigning ranks - the order was specified in the question and is the following: `very bad, bad, okay, good, very good`. One just has to assign numbers from $1$ to $5$ in that order. As for excluding tied ranks - this is a _very_ bad idea as you are tampering with your data and therefore the results. Imagine someone would do that in a double-blind clinical trial of a new drug...

Comment: @alesc  "inferior" only under certain conditions, superior under others. Are you aware of what those conditions are? That's ordering you mention is the ordering of the *original* categories, but what matters for the signed rank test is the ordering of the *differences*. By assigning the numbers 1 to 5 to those original categories you have actually assumed an interval scale where none existed. Excluding the tied ranks is not *tampering* with the data, it's actually conditioning on the information relevant to the question of whether there's a tendency of the ratings to increase or decrease.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree with your claims. We are dealing with the classic 5-point Likert scale. Also, I have never mentioned _interval_ scale in my answers. Ranks are ordinal data and assigning numbers from $1$ to $5$ does not change anything. The scale is still ordinal (not interval). And ordinal data is also appropriate for Wilcoxon signed-ranks test. You just have to set up your statistical software to treat it the right way (as ordinal, not interval).

Comment: We're dealing with a 5-point Likert scale *item*. (An actual Likert *scale* is a sum over such items.) This scale item is ordinal, you said so yourself. But by using scores where spacings between categories are equal you *are* imposing an interval scale -- those equal spacings you imposed is quite literally what an interval scale *is*. So you said it was ordinal, and then immediately treated it as interval. The fact that you failed to mention what you did is why your answer needs to be amended. As soon as you apply a signed rank test to ordinal pairs of data you treat the original as interval.

Comment: Configure your statistical software so that it will properly order the ordinal data with the following values and order: `very bad, bad, okay, good, very good`. What I am trying to say is that the difference between `very bad` and `okay` is _always_ $2$ ranks, regarding if you are using numbers $1,2,3,4,5$ or $10,20,30,40,50$.

Comment: Considering @Glen_b 's immense experience and contribution, I would like to have his comment on my answer suggesting Friedman test.

Comment: @rnso In general by initially converting the ordered categories to equispaced numbers you would have imposed an interval scale where there had been an ordinal one ... (so again, in general you'd need to have to made such a choice explicit) but in this case - because it's only the relative rankings within each group that matter and there's only two groups, that doesn't hurt anything. The Friedman in two groups is equivalent to a (two-tailed) sign test. Which is to say, your answer is the same as mine.

Comment: @rnso (Or at least it is the same if you either use the exact distribution for both or the corresponding asymptotic approximation for both; otherwise the p-values will tend to differ)

Comment: @ Glen_b : Thanks for your detailed explanation.  @alesc : Regarding your statement "You just have to set up your statistical software to treat it the right way (as ordinal, not interval)", what exactly do you mean in mathematical terms? How can this 'setup' be done in R, for example?

Comment: I do not have a lot of experience with R, I usually use SPSS or make an automated test with the Apache Common Math Java library. In SPSS, this is done by assigning numbers to the string literals. But as others pointed out, this is wrong. However, I still do not understand why - one can say that the difference between `very bad` and `good` is $3$ ranks, since there are two ordinal values between them. So if anyone could be so kind to explain to me why this calculated difference between two nominal values is wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @rnso unfortunately, in my initial response to you at one point I said 'group' (essentially 'treatment') when I meant 'pair' (or 'block' in Friedman terms) -- 'it's the rankings within each block that matter' (i.e. across, not within groups). Hopefully that didn't confuse things unduly.

Comment: @rnso In terms of 'set up', in R you can make your ordinal categorical variable a factor (even an ordinal factor), though for some functions you may need to deal with numbers. Whenever you do that (use numbers I mean), you must keep in mind those numbers don't have the interval property -- you can't just take differences (or sums) of the numbers you used. If you wouldn't - *a priori* - claim that a shift from `very bad` to `good` is completely identical to a shift from `bad` to `very good`, you can't claim it after you code them as numbers ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... (i.e. you can't just treat the shift of 3 categories with different start points both as "d=3".  So if you *do* code 'very bad' as 1 up to 'very good' as 5, you can't just take differences. You must first explicitly *assume* you have an interval scale, and then differences are meaningful.

Comment: @rnso note that in R you can just put your data in as `very bad` and so on. You can either make it a factor or an ordered factor and R will usually treat it properly automatically, at least in the vanilla R functions. Doing it that way also makes any choice to impose an interval scale explicit - when you physically type a command to recode your data, it's harder to think you didn't. It's always best, I think, to start with the original data as near as possible, and then explicitly do things to it (with commands) so you have a history of exactly what changes were made. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... If the data set is not big (where big could be 'more than fits in memory', say) you're generally better off starting from the original data and running an explicit clean/transform step. As data becomes nearer to big, you may need, as a practical matter, to archive a later step of the data and work with that. [I think that's 5 comments I've just added.]

Comment: Quite an information on ordered factors here. Thanks.

Comment: @rnso here's the data in R with the 2nd and 3rd columns as ordered factors (via `ordered`): . . . . `custrtg <- structure(list(customer = 1:15, product1 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("very.bad", 
"bad", "okay", "good", "very.good"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), product2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("very.bad", "bad", "okay", 
"good", "very.good"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), .Names = c("customer", 
"product1", "product2"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @rnso That's copypastable. Try `with(custrtg,product1-product2)`  ... It tells you something important. If you want to make the subtraction work, you'd have to explicitly choose to make it interval. You can't do it accidentally; it stops you  shooting yourself in the foot unless you mean to do it. So you can do this: `with(custrtg,as.numeric(product1)-as.numeric(product2))` ... but you're being explicit about it - you'are saying 'yes, I mean to treat those ordered categories as interval'. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

You have dependent ordinal data. You should use the [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) to test for significant difference between both products across all customers.

But given the data above, the Wilcoxon signed-rank test does not yield significant results.

Comment: I don't think you can use the signed rank test without making additional assumptions. For example, the signed rank test relies on ranking the absolute pair-differences, which means you're going to have to decide whether customer 2's  "good" to "bad" change is bigger, smaller or the same as customer 4's "very good" to "okay". Which suggests that you've likely imposed an *interval* scale at some point (it's hard to tell exactly what you did, though, because you didn't really explain it). That's a choice the OP might agree with but you would need to ask first.

Comment: To clarify: I think this is potentially a reasonable answer, but its particular assumptions should be more explicit. I think this answer could be improved if you explained how you proceeded from pairs like (`good`, `bad`) or (`very good`, `okay`) to a set of signed ranks, since this would make the assumptions made along the way more obvious.

Comment: The order of the answers is given, so assigning numerical ranks from $1$ to $5$ is trivial. Look at my other comment at your answer for more details.

Comment: Alesc, @Glen_b is right (and you are not): in signed-rank test you don't assign ranks to individual values, you assign ranks to *differences between pairs of values*. So you need to be able to compute the differences first. This is impossible with ordinal data.

Answer (score 1):

## Use the paired *t*-test

As long you have enough ratings (15 is sufficient, and I would be happy even with fewer) and some variation in the rating differences, there is no problem at all using the paired *t*-test. Then you get estimates that are very easy to interpret – the mean ratings on a 1–5 numeric scale + its difference (between products).

## R code

It’s very easy to do in R:

```
> ratings = c("very bad", "bad", "okay", "good", "very good")
> d = data.frame(
      customer = 1:15,
      product1 = factor(c(5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5),
                        levels=1:5, labels=ratings),
      product2 = factor(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3),
                        levels=1:5, labels=ratings))
> head(d)
  customer  product1  product2
1        1 very good  very bad
2        2      good       bad
3        3      okay       bad
4        4 very good      okay
5        5       bad very good
6        6      okay      good
```

First let’s check the average ratings:

```
> mean(as.numeric(d$product1))
    [1] 3.9333
    > mean(as.numeric(d$product2))
[1] 3.1333
```

And the *t*-test gives us:

```
> t.test(as.numeric(d$product1),
as.numeric(d$product2), paired=TRUE)
    Paired t-test

data:  as.numeric(d$product1) and as.numeric(d$product2)
t = 1.6, df = 14, p-value = 0.13
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.27137  1.87137
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                    0.8
```

The $p$-value is 0.13, which does *not* strongly suggest that products are rated differently, despite the apparent difference of 0.8 (but do note the quite confidence interval – we really need more data).

## Fake data?

Curiously, and unexpectedly, an unpaired *t*-test gives a **lower** *p*-value.

```
> t.test(as.numeric(d$product1),
             as.numeric(d$product2), paired=FALSE)
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  as.numeric(d$product1) and as.numeric(d$product2)
t = 1.86, df = 27.6, p-value = 0.073
[…]
```

This does suggest that the example data are fake. For real data, one would expect a (quite high) positive correlation between ratings from the same customer. Here the correlation is negative (though not statistically significantly so):

```
> cor.test(as.numeric(d$product1), as.numeric(d$product2))

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  as.numeric(d$product1) and as.numeric(d$product2)
t = -1.38, df = 13, p-value = 0.19
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.73537  0.18897
sample estimates:
     cor 
-0.35794
```

## Missing data

When not all customers have rated both products (i.e., unbalanced data), a better approach is using a mixed-effects model:

Let’s first convert the data to numeric form:

```
> d2 = d
> d2[,-1] = lapply(d2[,-1], as.numeric)
```

And convert it to ‘long’ form:

```
> library(tidyr)
> d3 = gather(d2, product, value, -customer)
```

And finally fit a mixed-effects model with customer as a random effect:

```
> l = lme(value~product, random=~1|customer, data=d3)
> summary(l)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: d3 
     AIC    BIC  logLik
  101.91 107.24 -46.957

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | customer
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:  3.7259e-05   1.1751

Fixed effects: value ~ product 
                  Value Std.Error DF t-value p-value
(Intercept)      3.9333   0.30342 14 12.9633  0.0000
productproduct2 -0.8000   0.42910 14 -1.8644  0.0834
[…]
```

The $p$-value is 0.0834. Usually for balanced data it will be **almost identical** to the *p*-value from a paired *t*-test. Here it is closer to the *p*-value of an **unpaired** *t*-test, because of the negative correlation. Note that the variance for the customer effect (random intercept) is almost zero. This would rarely happen with real data.

## Summary

In summary, use the paired *t*-test. Then you get estimates that are easy to interpret (simple numerical averages).

If not all customers have rated both products, use a mixed effects model instead. (This will give approximately the same results as the paired *t*-test when they *have* all rated both products, so you might as well always use it.)