# Comparing two groups of ordinal survey data?

Tags: survey, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am trying to compare two (theoretical) independent groups of surveys with a 5 point ordinal scale (1 - greatly disagree, 5 - greatly agree). Both group A and group B received the same 10 questions and 5 point scale.

In order to analyze the data, which test would be best to run? I am trying to find out if there is a significant difference between the two groups.

I am not sure whether the Mann-Whitney test is appropriate.

I do apologize for the foolish question, but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This post may be helpful to you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142903/develop-a-statistical-test-to-distinguish-two-products

Comment: Are you going to sum or average the 10 questions? Are they considered to measure the same construct? Are the scores bunched up around the extremes?