# How to compare process outcomes for quality?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I'm comparing processes A and B for quality. I made each process generate 1,000 outcomes, for 1,000 inputs.

The inputs were identical for processes A and B, so `outcome_a1` is directly comparable to `outcome_b1` etc. So are able to say "`outcome_a50` is of better quality than `outcome_b50`, on input #50".

Now I want to know which process is better in general: A or B? Or are they equal?

I have manually compared these 1000 pairs of outcomes: (outcome_a1 vs outcome_b1), (outcome_a2 vs outcome_b2) etc.

Turns out, A is better than B 52x, B is better than A 13x, and they are of the same quality 935x. 52+13+935=1000.

Now I want to know, how do I evaluate statistical significance of this experiment? How would things change if I compared only 500 pairs instead of 1000 (with the same win/tie proportions)? 10 pairs?

There's no apriori reason to believe A is better than B, or vice versa.

Sorry for the basic question, I don't even know the right terminology to know what to google for!

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142918/17230) for an illustration of using the [sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test) for a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about [hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

I guess that the difficulty is not in the testing but in choosing the proper hypothesis to test.

There are some alternatives I'll list.

The most common hypothesis is for [difference in mean](http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-means.aspx).
Since you are comparing pairs, I assume you don't use this alternative since it is hard to specify the absolute quality while identifying quality difference is easier or that the mean itself is not of interest.

So, we can move to compare pairs.
Note that we can treat each pair as a sample and consider only the existence of difference and not the size of the difference.
Now we can [use as the null hypothesis that the mean](http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/mean.aspx?Tutorial=AP) (of the difference) is zero.

A different approach is to use [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval).
Instead of just saying that the probability that B is better is 52/1000, you can compute an interval in which this probability is likely to be.

All of the methods above depend on the number of samples.
The more samples you have, the more likely you will get the right results.

Comment: Sorry, this is too vague for me, I need something more concrete. Something that takes off where my example finished.

Comment: Ok, we can get into details. Which of the above direction fits more your goal? Are you interested in knowing in the quality in process A is higher in general (fist option in the answer above)? Are you interested in the knowing if per input A is higher (second option)? Are you interested in estimating the probability the A is higher (the confidence interval option)?

Comment: I can see A is better than B. The challenge is to quantify our certainty in this conclusion (is it due to chance, or is this type of 52-13-935 result repeatable?). I thought statistical significance may be the right tool for this.

Comment: In case you know that A is better I would go for quantifying how better it is (confidence interval).